# simple formal proof $ \lfloor (z+1)/c \rfloor \lt z $ for $ c \ge 2 $

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

My math is a little rusty. I wish to formally prove to myself that $$\lfloor (z+1)/c \rfloor \le z$$ where $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c \ge 2$ for use in a larger inductive proof. The statement seems self-evident given the constraint $c \ge 2$. Still though, I wish to prove it formally, but I'm not sure how to deal with the floor function.

So, so far what I've done is ignore it and instead try and prove $$(z+1)/c \le z$$ To do this, I've rewritten the inequality moving $z$'s to one side: $$1/(c-1) \le z$$ which again looks to be self evident. But how can I really nail this one down? Am I on the right track at least? Or is there a better method of proof available for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $z\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ we have $z+1\leq z+z\leq c z$ and therefore
$$\left\lfloor{z+1\over c}\right\rfloor\leq{z+1\over c}\leq z\ .$$

Comment: If I were a skeptic, how would I go about proving $z+1 \le 2z$?

Comment: Ah, it may simply be another proof by induction?: for $z \ge 1$

base: $z=1$ $$1+1 \le 2$$

inductive: assuming $k+1 \le 2k$, prove $k+1+1 \le 2(k+1)$

$$(k+1)+1 \le 2k+1$$ -- add 1 to assumption
$$(k+1)+1 \le 2k+1 \lt 2k+1+1$$
$$\le 2(k+1)$$

Comment: Or $z+1 \le z+z$ would work too :) Thanks for your help Christian!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{z + 1}{c} \le z \iff (c - 1)z \ge 1$$